# Returns a specific species based on the id

Tags: javascript, function, object, for-loop

I'm trying to return a specific species based on the id. The objects themselves aren't present. But here's my code thus far:

```
function findById (data, id) {
  const result = null

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var bug = data[i]
    if (bug.id = id) {
      return bug
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

It keeps kicking back the error: `AssertionError: expected { Object (species, id, ...) } to deeply equal { Object (species, id, ...) }`

Comment: What does the statement in your code `if (bug.id = id)` do? What is the operator `=` doing?

Comment: Please provide an example of the function's input: `data` and `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `==` or `===` instead of `=` in your if statement:

```
function findById (data, id) {
  const result = null

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var bug = data[i]
    if (bug.id === id) {
      return bug
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

Comment: Wow. That was it. Strictly equals. Thank you